# Rename local branch which isn't pushed into remote repo yet

Tags: git

I've created a new branch in local with below command and started working on code changes.

```
master> git checkout -b "mybranch"
```

Later, I realized that I needed to follow our standard and that I should have created "feature/mybranch" instead of "mybranch"

I've not pushed any of my local changes to remote yet. I would like to know how I can rename this local repo without deleting this local branch and re-creating new one?

Thanks!

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch
Checkout the `-m` option